Регистрация пользователя через firebase
Пишу приложение на react и в данный момент занимаюсь авторизацией и регистрацией пользователей с помощью firebase. В целом со всем разобрался и все работает, но при регистрации пользователя происходит сразу же его авторизация, а мне бы хотелось просто вывести сообщение об успехе/неудаче и перебросить пользователя на форму авторизации. В документации не нашел, как избежать этого поведения, если такой пункт там имеется, прошу указать где именно, а если нет, то помочь с решением. Пробовал делать отдельное состояние в провайдере, тогда поведение то, что мне нужно, но на какое то время приложение принимает вид авторизованного пользователя
